# Problem in Unity when destroying an instantiated object- Destroys all clones of the original object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, I'm trying to recreate a DDR kind of thing and I'm just trying to get the basic gameplay down. I'm still a novice when it comes to game dev but I have a little bit of experience. Right now I'm instantiating a random arrow of 4 different arrow directions, and when I do that I put it in a list. The first arrow of the list is always the next arrow in the scene, and I use RemoveAt() to ensure that. The problem I'm getting is that when I get two of the same arrow directions (coming from the same original prefab) in a row in the list, deleting one will delete all of them if they are consecutive. It only does it like this; for example, if my arrow order is left, left, down, it deletes both lefts. If my arrow order is left, down, left, it only deletes the first left and I just can't figure out why. I know it's not the names because I've tried changing that each time but that did nothing, I've tried using a queue, everything I do I just can't get it to work and I need help.

```
spawnedBox = Instantiate(spawningBox, new Vector3(spawnPos, -6, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

arrows.Add(spawnedBox);
```

(different file)

```
destroyArrow = FindObjectOfType<Blocks>().arrows[0];
FindObjectOfType<Blocks>().arrows.RemoveAt(0); Destroy(destroyArrow);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add an [mcve] of your code.  We can't help you without it.

Comment: Add the code of how you are deleting the GameObject

Comment: `spawnedBox = Instantiate(spawningBox, new Vector3(spawnPos, -6, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;`
`arrows.Add(spawnedBox);`
(different file)
`destroyArrow = FindObjectOfType<Blocks>().arrows[0];`
`FindObjectOfType<Blocks>().arrows.RemoveAt(0);`
`Destroy(destroyArrow);`
Sorry this is my first post I don't really know how to format

Comment: In the code you posted you are always destroying the first element of the array (you are passing the index 0)

Comment: I want to destroy the index 0, but it removes all of the same types of arrows even if they aren't in index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate each arrow and store it into an array. Then when required it, destroyed if from the array. You can try something like this:

```
public GameObject[] ArrowsArray;

//Here you instantiate the arrow and you store it 
ArrowsArray[index] = Instantiate (originalPref, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

//Here you destroy the gameObject and remove it from the array
Destroy(ArrowsArray[index]);
ArrowsArray.RemoveAt (index);
```

Comment: `List<T>` is a thing.